# Libreoffice: Generate same figure with data in another sheet

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

I have several sheets with data (corresponding to different years) arranged in the exact same way. I have created figures on sheet 1. Is there a way to have the same figures generated with the data in the other sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the chart and modify the data range:

1. Copy the chart und paste it into sheet 2;
2. Right-click on the chart, select "edit":

   [image]
3. Right-click again and select "Data Ranges...";

   [image]
4. In the data range entry box, modify every occurence of the name of the originating so it fits the new sheet's name, leave everything else as it is;

   [image]
5. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd> - that's all.

Comment: Thanks! One note following a first try: the sheet name may appear more than once in that line, all references need to be changed.

Comment: @Joce yes you're right - i will adapt my answer accordingly.